# How to get the address of a struct field through reflect in GO

Tags: go, serialization, reflection

I'm working on a code to deserialize streams of bytes into objects and I'm stuck on getting the pointer of the field of a struct.

Basically how the code works is as follows: it gets the pointer to a struct, then depending on the type it serializes it, ex. if it's an integer it takes the next 4 bytes. The tricky case is if it's a struct because I have to recursively run Deserialize on all of its attributes and I don't know how to get the address of its field to pass them to Deserialize.

```
func Deserialize(objPtr interface{}, b []byte) (bytesRead int) {
    // it should be the address of the object

    val := reflect.ValueOf(objPtr).Elem()
    valPtr := reflect.ValueOf(objPtr)

    // check if either the object or *object is Serializable
    _, isSerializable := (val.Interface()).(Serializable)
    _, bo := (valPtr.Interface()).(Serializable)
    isSerializable = isSerializable || bo

    // specific type serialization
    if isSerializable{
        return objPtr.(Serializable).Deserializebyte(b)
    }

    switch val.Kind() {
    case reflect.Uint32, reflect.Int, reflect.Int32:
        res := reflect.ValueOf(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(b[:4]))
        valPtr.Set(res)
        return 4
    case reflect.Uint64, reflect.Int64:
        res := reflect.ValueOf(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(b[:8]))
        valPtr.Set(res)
        return 8
    case reflect.Struct:
        n_bytes := 0
        for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {

            // stuck in here
            valPtr.Elem()

            // I don't think the next line works
            last_n_bytes := Deserialize(&(valPtr.Elem().Field(i).Interface()), b)
            n_bytes += last_n_bytes
            b = b[last_n_bytes:]
        }
        //valPtr.Set(res)
        return n_bytes
    default:
        panic("this panic is for debug, every case should be handled above")
        res := val.Bytes()
        valPtr.Set(res)
        return len(val.Bytes())
    }
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the reflect API to get the [address](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Addr) of the field:

```
last_n_bytes := Deserialize(valPtr.Elem().Field(i).Addr().Interface(), b)
```

The `superint` example panics because the application takes the address of an unexported field through the reflect API.  That's not allowed because it would allow another package to modify the field.

Here's a working example with [exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) fields:

```
type superint struct {
    A int
    B int
}

func (s *superint) lol() {}

type a interface{ lol() }

func main() {
    i := superint{A: 1, B: 9}
    valPtr := reflect.ValueOf(&i)
    fmt.Printf("%v \n", &i.A)
    fmt.Printf("%v \n", valPtr.Elem().Field(0).Addr().Interface())
}
```

Comment: I tried that with a simpler example but I get panic. `type superint struct {
 a int
 b int
};

func (s*superint) lol()  {

}

type a interface {
 lol()
}

func debug(){
 i := superint{
  a : 1,
  b : 9,
 }
 valPtr := reflect.ValueOf(&i)
 fmt.Printf("%v \n", &i.a)
 fmt.Printf("%v \n", valPtr.Elem().Field(0).Addr().Interface())
}`

Comment: I'm so used to public and private that didn't understood what "unexported" mean, Thanks!!!